# What's the origin of using the cup-stacking-girl shouting "OH MY GOSH!" in dubstep mixes?

Tags: technique

In a lot of dubstep remixes I hear there is a clip of a girl screaming "OH MY GOSH!" I'm wondering why this is such a popular splice, what its origin is or why it is so prevalent in dubstep mixes.

The clip sounds like it's from a video I've seen on YouTube of a girl stacking and collapsing cups very rapidly. When she completes she starts celebrating by shouting "YES! OH MY GOSH!" over and over.

Did it just appear in one mix that's been copied and changed or is it also appearing in original works?

Comment: I've heard this too, always in songs (or remixes of songs) by [Skrillex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skrillex), and I made the same mental connection to the cup-stacking girl (about 11 seconds into [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qPg_j2M3B_Y) for those unfamiliar with what OP is referring to).

Comment: [Relevant to your interests](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PapG53eIM1M).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems like Skrillex just really liked it and it became something of a meme due to their song (and probably due to the original video).  From [an interview](http://nashvillenightsblog.com/interview-skrillex/):

> **Who’s the voice behind the “YES! OH MY GOD!” sample used in Scary Monsters & Nice Sprites?**
>
> This girl on youtube who does this cup stacking thing. She filmed herself breaking her record and freaking out saying “OMG OMG OMG” a thousand times. One of the best videos on youtube for sure! It was the perfect sample before the drop. Her voice really pumps you up! Here’s the link

Comment: I love the excitement on her face. She's just so proud.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it sounds exactly the same as Ryan Lee's character Carey in the 2011 J.J Abrams directed film "Super 8". When the boys break into the school and view footage of scientists studying the creature. Doctor Woodward is briefly captured by the creature and Carey exclaims "Oh my God!". The clue is the audio just before the "Oh my God!" which matches the film exactly, but is not in the cup stacking girl video. Skrillex sampled Super 8.